# Why is magnetic ’t Hooft loop operator independent of its path in$Z_2$ gauge theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, topological-order, magnetic-monopoles, lattice-gauge-theory

One important concept for $Z_2$ gauge theory is magnetic ’t Hooft loop operator $\tilde{W}_{\tilde{\Gamma}}$ along a non-contractible loop $\tilde{\Gamma}$ on the dual lattice of the torus is:
$$\tilde{W}_{\tilde{\Gamma}}=\prod_{(\vec{x}, j) \in \tilde{\Gamma}} \sigma_{j}^{x}(\vec{x})$$
[image]

This operator represents the product of $σ_x$ operators of the links of the lattice threaded by the loop $\tilde{\Gamma}$. However, many reference says that, if we consider the case in gauge invariant sector, i.e. $Q(\vec{x})=\sigma_{1}^{x}(\vec{x}) \sigma_{1}^{x}\left(\vec{x}-e_{1}\right) \sigma_{2}^{x}(\vec{x}) \sigma_{2}^{x}\left(\vec{x}-e_{2}\right)=1$, *the actual path is unimportant*. I cannot understand the reason of this argument.

Similarly, we can also define magnetic charge operator:
$$\tau^{z}(\vec{r})=\prod_{(\vec{x}, j) \text { pierced by } \tilde{\gamma}(\vec{r})} \sigma_{j}^{x}(\vec{x})$$
[image]

Also, reference argues that in the gauge-invariant sector, with $Q(x) = 1$ everywhere, this operator depends only on the location $r$ of the dual lattice and *it is independent of the shape of the Dirac string*(the rest of the path $\tilde{\gamma}(\vec{r})$ with its endpoint at r). I still cannot understand the reason of this argument.

Comment: What happens if you take the loop in your first picture and you act with Q(x) on one of the vertices neighboring your loop? Hint: use the fact that sigma^x squares to 1.